# RadGridView, Changing Colour of Filter icon

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, telerik, radgridview

I am applying a template and styles to a telerik RadGridView to adjust the colour of the filter icon when it is selected.

My problem is that I apply a style like this,

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}" ></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

The style is generated by expression blend when I selected the option to generate template.

The problem is that I want to apply a theme like this,

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls.StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.Windows7Theme();
```

But then all of a sudden the style that expression blend generated doesn't match the theme. Is there a way to get the style as defined by the theme?

If I then remove parts of the style to only define the dropdown style like this (which means the rest of the header won't be changed and the theme will match the resulting style),

```
<Style TargetType="GridView:FilteringDropDown">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DistinctFilterControlTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

It works if the theme is off, it applies the template only to the filtering drop down, but if the theme is on then the style gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the curious nature of this question, I went ahead and searched for a very long while to find the answer.

To me it would seem that there is not a property that controls the color inside the filter icon on the Gridview.

To support this claim I used the Visual Style Builder, Telerik's own tool, to change around any property I could find that may have an affect on the color of the icon.

As you can see here, I was able to change the colors of the areas outside the icon, but also note that the "Image" property is set as a picture:

[image]

What this means is that when you hover over the button, the control itself most likely replaces the image with another one located somewhere within the Telerik suite.

Comment: I'd assume it's cause your post is not tagged silverlight :P. The difference aren't always the largest, but there may be a chance that in SL you may change that color. Lemme know what you find out.

Comment: I think we are looking at different things. The control I am using consists of Paths making up the icon, not an image. When I looked at the Visual Style Builder it seemed to only be for ASP .NET. Opps, I need to clarify that I am using silverlight.

Comment: Apologies KreepN. I wrote this question in rather a hurry. Updated now.

Comment: I figured as much, no big. I didn't see anything on the Telerik site regarding the tools for silverlight though, so you may have a harder time breaking down the structure of the tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack really, but I had to go into the dll, Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows7.dll using ILSpy and look up the xaml file called,

gridviewheadercell.xaml

If I then copied that over, and applied the style. I then had to go back to expression blend, and edit the template for PART_DistinctFilterControl and go from there.

It works, but if we at some stage decide to apply a different theme, or telerik change the current theme then it could cause issues.

I am open to better suggestions.